# What's this icon in the Scene Builder Hierarchy Panel?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I'm using JavaFX Scene Builder and running into some problems with sizing components.

I noticed that on some of my hierarchy nodes there's an icon I don't recognise, and I wondered whether the hierarchy was trying to alert me to some kind of problem that I've inadvertently caused.

Anyone know what this icon means?  I've put a red square around it to highlight the one I mean.[image: Hierarchy panel with icon]

Comment: I think it means you have set the `ScrollPane` as the graphic of the `Tab`, instead of setting it as the content.

Comment: Spot on!  No wonder my controls weren't being laid out.  Thanks!

(Make your comment into an answer and I'll happily accept it.)